# Xamarin monodroid - how to track .net memory leaks

Tags: memory-leaks, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have lots of memory allocated in my mono droid program which doesn't appear to directly belong to either the Dalvik or the Mono heaps. Also, I can't figure out how to track .NET memory leaks.

When I call

adb shell dumpsys meminfo MyProgram.Droid

This is the output:

```
** MEMINFO in pid 1364 [MyProgram.Droid] **
                     Shared  Private     Heap     Heap     Heap
               Pss    Dirty    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
            ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
   Native       36       24       36    38080    37775      124
   Dalvik     6934    15164     6572    16839    15384     1455
   Cursor        0        0        0
   Ashmem        0        0        0
Other dev        4       36        0
 .so mmap    12029     2416     9068
.jar mmap        0        0        0
.apk mmap    16920        0        0
.ttf mmap        3        0        0
.dex mmap     2299      296        8
Other mmap       64       24       36
  Unknown    28920     8216    28728
    TOTAL    67209    26176    44448    54919    53159     1579
```

I assume that the "Unknown" section is the mono framework, including the .NET heap. However when I call

GC.GetTotalMemory(true)

It tells me that only 5Mb of memory is allocated. That leaves 23Mb which I cannot trace (and there's 38Mb of allocated native heap)

Additionally, I don't see that Xamarin have any tools for tracking .NET memory leaks. I've added garbage collection logging with

```
adb shell setprop debug.mono.log gc,gref
```

But this is incredibly verbose and hard to read and doesn't even include allocation sizes.

At this point I don't know what to do to track down the resulting leaks. Since the allocations appear to be on the native heap, do I need to use the NDK in order to track down what's going on? Are there any tools I can use on the C# side to track the .NET leaks?

Thanks!